# WPF Is Polygon inside a Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, polygon, intersection

I have some generated parallelograms (Polygons) in a list and I add these to a Canvas. Before I do that I want to determine if there are parallelograms not inside the bounds of the Canvas. If there are parallelograms outside, I could delete them, because the user would not see them anyway.

Is there a (fast) way to test if a Polygon is inside a Canvas (inside a Rectangle)?
Maybe I could use Regions and test for intersection, but I don't know how to create a Region from a Polygon.

Comment: Not a fast way.  Unless you're dealing with hundreds or more of polygons that are not visible, you're better off just adding them all to the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may check if the Rectangle returned from the `Bounds` property of the polygon geometry intersects with the Canvas Rectangle:

```
var canvasRect = new Rect(canvas.RenderSize);
var polygonRect = polygon.RenderedGeometry.Bounds;
var intersects = canvasRect.IntersectsWith(polygonRect);
```